# Installing msvcr90.dll easy way! (without C++ Redistributable Package)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dllimport, dllregistration

My program is a converted python file to exe file. The problem with this exe file is that it does not run without python installed and it only needs mscvr90.dll! I don't want to install C++ Redistributable Package just for this dll file! That big fat package! If I copy this msvcr90.dll to my application folder it just won't work!

The file path of msvcr90.dll when I install python is:

C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_x-ww_d08d0375

I don't really know how python installs this file but there has to be an easy way to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VCRT libraries are hardly a 'big fat' package.  I'm looking at them now and they're just over 2mb - almost nothing.

That said the only real way to circumvent the SxS linking would be to change the manifest of the executable that is linking to the files.  You can use Visual Studio to open the .exe and edit the manifest to not use SxS linking.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile with /MT then it wont dynamically link to the msvcr90 library.